# Sprockets encoding error on js file: invalid UTF-8 byte sequence

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, sprockets

A Sprockets::EncodingError exception is thrown when I include a file with characters that are valid utf-8.

The line in question is:

```
* Copyright (c) 2010 - 2011 Johan Säll Larsson
```

If I replace the ä character, the problem goes away, but I don't want to have to remember to edit this vendor file everytime I update it.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I found the solution via the comments on [this Sprockets issue](https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets/issues/87#issuecomment-1344825):

I simply saved the file as utf-8, (TextMate has an option to do this when you chose 'Save As'), and the problem went away.

The commenter @shedd also created [a useful rake task](https://gist.github.com/1301199/a19adcb7687f2adfc927c9e8da3d716960833797) to find assets which are not encoded properly.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. In SublimeText2 you can fix it via _File_ > _Save with Encoding_ > _UTF8_.

Answer (score 1):

This is fixed in trunk. All files use utf-8 without BOM.