# Ruby 1.9 throwing javascript encoding error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

So, I updated my Ruby to 1.9.2, followed this:

- Make sure 'config.encoding = "utf-8"' is there in application.rb file.
- Make sure you are using 'mysql2' gem
- Putting '# encoding: utf-8' on top of rake file.
- Above 'Starter::Application.initialize!' line in environment.rb file, add following two lines:

  - Encoding.default_external = Encoding::UTF_8
  - Encoding.default_internal = Encoding::UTF_8

and now all my Ruby code is working right, but my assets/javascript/application.js is loaded only with this code:

```
throw Error("Encoding::CompatibilityError: incompatible character encodings: ASCII-8BIT and UTF-8")
```

how can i define assets encoding?

ps.: i didn't try to precompile yet, this is happening on development mode

Answer (score 1):

[Read the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837350/sprockets-encoding-error-on-js-file-invalid-utf-8-byte-sequence).  Sounds like it's the same issue you're looking at.  It sounds like the solution is to open the `.js` file with a text editor and save it as UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: i figured out what was causing, it was the ckeditor
    "//= require ckeditor/ckeditor"
but i still need to use the ckeditor

Comment: I think that should be fine.  Again, try opening the `.js` file with a basic text editor (like TextMate), and then specifying the encoding to be `UTF-8` and saving it back out again.

Comment: saving as UTF-8 wasn't enought, i had to change somethings on the gem .js file, posted as an issue https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor/issues/81

Comment: Well I'm glad you were able to solve it.  Sorry I couldn't be of more help.