# rails : heroku error logs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, deployment, heroku

Okau, I have a rails app which works fine on my localhost. Now I have a new problem on the logs which seems to have an issue with the syntax. I have javascript include tags as below :

Okay This is the main error

```
ActionView::Template::Error (/app/app/assets/javascripts/jq_scroll/jq_animate.js has a invalid UTF-8 byte sequence):
```

How do I resolve this?

Comment: I tried removing all the javascript files (include tag) and the app worked. there seems to be some sort of syntax error in my code. Any help?

Comment: Looks like a sprocket issue.. have a look at this Question 


 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837350/sprockets-encoding-error-on-js-file-invalid-utf-8-byte-sequence

Answer (score 0):

Are you interpolating any I18n string into the JS file or does it contain any non-ASCII characters? If so, try adding a "magic comment" at the top of the file (assuming the file has the extension .js.erb):

```
<% # coding: utf-8 %>
// JS file content...
```